# How to create unique Id per request for REST API in Spring-boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, request, log4j

I need to make my logs (log4j engine) to be more informative with a unique id per request for my REST API in Spring-Boot application.

I want to avoid using a superclass which got requestId field and extend from it.

I tried to look for a good example over the web, but it wasn't so clear.

Is there any best practice that I can use?

Comment: Use MDC....https://www.baeldung.com/mdc-in-log4j-2-logback

Answer (score 1):

Using a field for such a feature would just cause problems during the integration testing on the first glance..

Ideally, just follow an SRP principle and include the generation logic inside a dedicated class which you could make an injectable `@Component`.. `MyIdGenerator` etc.

There you could have a synchronized method `generateId()`.

Now you could use it in whichever controller it is needed and also you could set-up your integration test more easily and have more control over them.

**Update:**

You could take also advantage of `HandleInterceptorAdapter` if this should be a global strategy:

```
@Component
public class RequestInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
            throws Exception {

    /* generate unique id here and log what is needed */

    }
```

You can encapsulate the ID generation and logging inside this class.

Comment: I want something which is more of a spring infrastructure like a configuration class to make it automated. I don't want to change my Request & Response POJO's

Comment: I was not suggesting altering the Pojos by any means. Check my update, this might be more adequate in that case

Comment: I found this example: https://medium.com/@d.lopez.j/spring-boot-setting-a-unique-id-per-request-dd648efef2b. I just don't succeed to print it to the log for some reason

Answer (score 0):

There are several best practices used as follows:

1. Use AOP Refer :[AOP used for controller layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55948389/how-can-i-start-and-stop-a-timer-in-different-classes/55949813#55949813)
2. Use MDC
3. Use MDC with AOP
   [MDC with AOP](https://dzone.com/articles/setting-up-mdc-context-with-aop-in-spring-boot-app)